# Using shared project in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have the following problem to solve: We currently have two different web projects utilizing TypeScript and NPM. We have certain things in both projects that are identical. We want to move these to a shared project and then draw the shared classes into our two projects by using NPM.

What I have tried is to create a package.json in my shared components project, effectively making it an NPM package (name is "sharedcomponents"). Then, I included the following in the two web projects' package.json files, under dependencies:

```
"sharedcomponents": "file:../../sharedcomponents"
```

I am also referencing typings, in my tsd.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../../sharedcomponents/shared.d.ts" />
```

The shared components project's NPM package is configured with the entry point "index.js". That file looks like this:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = require('shared');
```

The "shared" file is shared.js, which in turn includes other files.

Here comes the problem that I have encountered. When I attempt to import classes from my shared components package, I cannot find anything.

```
import * as SharedComponents from 'sharedcomponents';

private _button: SharedComponents.TextButton;
```

The compiler complains that it cannot find TextButton. I also get no intellisense, like I do on the React stuff I have included from NPM.

Have I missed something important? I have looked at the Node and NPM sites but found nothing on using "local" NPM packages like I want to.

Comment: As you're using TSD, can you use also npm `@types/*` to avoid `/// <reference` ? Is your version of TypeScript > 2.x ?

Comment: Why using npm for a local package? Can it just be just included in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Yes, we are using TypeScript 2.1.

Romain: Could you please elaborate on how to include this is the tsconfig.json?

Comment: OK, I got it to recognize the classes. But, during runtime, I now get this problem:

http://localhost:8080/sharedcomponents/shared.js  404 (Not Found)

It's like it is trying to load the shared component package as a file...

Comment: The error 404 can be resolved here only with more info (build, serve...) which can be long. Alternative options to evaluate, all resulting in having the shared files in the project folder and needing a manual synchronisation: 
- If the source code is in git : git submodule, 
- npm private repository, 
- custom npm script to copy shared files